# How can I change at which viewport width the off canvas navbar is shown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

With the [Jasny Bootstrap Off canvas plugin](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas), it's possible to show the `.navbar` as off canvas menu for mobile sites as shown in [this example](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navbar-offcanvas/).

By default the layout switches to the off canvas menu for viewport widths less then 768px.

How can I change this to show the off canvas menu at 1280px or less?

Comment: Great addition to Bootstrap 3. Love your work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build a customized version of both Bootstrap and Jasny Bootstrap and change `@grit-float-breakpoint`.

The easiest way to do this is using the web based customizers

- [Bootstrap customizer](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system)
- [Jasny Bootstrap customizer](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/customize/#grid-system)